# Is there a way to duplicate entire data from one project to the other in Django?

Tags: django

So I've made and been running a beta test of my project for a couple of months. It is a CRUD application, where user posts some stuff. 
The thing is, I realized that I might have to pivot the item a little, so I'm planning to build a new project from the beginning. But the posts of my beta testers have to be kept as-is, so I want to migrate(or duplicate) the entire data to this new project.
Given that I have the exact same model as the original project in the new one, is there a way to make this possible? Or (I strongly hope not, but) do I have to manually copy+paste all the data? The posts are quite private so the users wouldn't want me to copy+paste them. 
Thank you very much in advance. :)

FYI, I'm using AWS EC2 and Postgres.

Comment: If all the posts are saved in the database, could you please explain in more details what exactly is the problem to transfer them to the new application? This is most likely just a database question. You just need to filter your posts by the usernames or dates?

Comment: @AndreyBorzenko The thing is I'm trying to move the data from one project to another. The two projects are separate and independent to one another. So the database are different(models can be designed identical, though). Is it still possible in this case? I'm a newbie in Django :)

Comment: Just Create a new database by ```python manage.py makemigrations```, and then add you data by exporting the new sql file.

Comment: you can export data via [dumpdata command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata) and insert them into another database via [loaddata command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-loaddata), assuming the databases are compatible.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko So this works between two separate applications?

Comment: It dumps your DB records into JSON file, and then the another command can insert the JSON data back to database. The loading command does not care which database are you loading it into, it cares only about the DB structure.